# Positivity of a sequence of rv's converging in probability to an almost surely strictly positive random variable

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $X_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}X$ with $\mathbb{P}\left[X>0\right]=1$. I want to prove that, for all $\varepsilon>0$, it holds $\mathbb{P}\left[|X_n|\geq \varepsilon\right]\rightarrow 1$.

My attempt: $\varepsilon\leq |X_n|\leq |X_n-X|+|X|$ implies $[\varepsilon\leq |X_n|]\subseteq [\varepsilon\leq |X_n-X|+|X|]$ or

$$\mathbb{P}\left[|X_n|\geq \varepsilon\right]\leq \mathbb{P}[ |X_n-X|+|X|\geq \varepsilon]$$

but this goes in the order direction, since I have to find out a converging-to-one lower bound for $\mathbb{P}\left[|X_n|\geq \varepsilon\right]$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not true that for each fixed $\varepsilon$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left[|X_n|\geq \varepsilon\right]=1$. For example, take $X_n=X$, we do not necessarily have in this setting that $\mathbb{P}\left[X\geq \varepsilon\right]=1$.

Comment: you'r right, I guess the statement should be formulated in $\exists \varepsilon$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}P[|X_n|\geq \varepsilon]=1$.

Comment: But if you take $X$ such that $P(X=1/k)=2^{-k}, k\geqslant 1$, and $X_n=X$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}P[|X_n|\geq \varepsilon]=\sum_{k\geqslant 1: 1/k>\varepsilon}2^{-k}<1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be such that $P(X=1/k)=2^{-k}, k\geqslant 1$ and $X_n=X$. Then for each positive $\varepsilon$,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}P[|X_n|\geqslant \varepsilon]=\sum_{k\geqslant 1: 1/k>\varepsilon}2^{-k}<1.
$$
Conclusion: it is possible that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}P[|X_n|\geqslant \varepsilon]=1$ fail for each positive $\varepsilon$.